# firefox mac os: how to remap cmd+r to f5?

Tags: firefox

I'm used to hit the f5 key for reloading page on linux/windows. Is there a way to remap reload page shortcut cmd+r to f5 on mac os?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remap any shortcut on macOS - so long as the item you wish to change has a Menu entry.

To demonstrate on Safari - I don't have Firefox..

Original menu -

[image]

So, to change it - System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts >App Shortcuts
Click the + button, set your required app, the menu *exact* name & your new key command

[image]

& here is your new menu -

[image]