# Is it possible restart Mac from 2nd monitor only without mouse?

Tags: mojave, mac-mini

My Mac has an issue where sometimes the primary monitor won't wake up, but the Mac thinks it is connected. So In such cases, I only see my secondary (much smaller) monitor.

Typically I cannot find the mouse cursor so I'm left with a monitor but no way to *do* anything. Restarting fixes it but I end up having to force-power-down by holding the MacMini power button then restarting... is there a way I can access the Restart menu option in this scenario instead?

Comment: Take a look at this answer regarding the overriding issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381912/119271

Comment: Thanks, I'll come to back that after I upgrade to Catalina at some point,

Answer (score 2):

You can set a key command to it, same as any menu item, though you're flying blind. If any app wants you to confirm save/discard you may not see it.

<sup>Whilst I'm aware this is really an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) I've answered the Y ;)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain/point me to this?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387505/firefox-mac-os-how-to-remap-cmdr-to-f5/387507#387507 for a similar one I wrote today